# What are some of the best cosmology textbooks to read after Ryden?

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, education

Introduction to Cosmology by Barbara Ryden is perhaps the best book to introduce someone to the subject. After reading Ryden, what books should a student who's interested to pursue research in cosmology look upon? Is Cosmological Physics by John Peacock a good option? There are some negative reviews of the book though. I personally think the book by Peebles is a little bit old fashioned and disorganised. Modern Cosmology by Scott Dodelson maybe a tough read for someone who has read only Ryden.

Comment: I found Mukhanov - Physics Foundation of Cosmology online. To me it goes more in depth, at least for the chapters I could follow relatively easily. Another on the level of Ryden that I like is Matt Roots.

Answer (score 1):

[Cosmology, Steven Weinberg](https://books.google.es/books/about/Cosmology.html?id=nqQZdg020fsC&redir_esc=y)

Best regards.